# EXCEL: how to fix #NAME? error when appying IFERROR to ratio calculation

Tags: excel

- I want to calculate a ratio each day. I'm using the GCD formula to do this
- My sheet obviously therefore has a bunch of cells ready to fill in future ratios, with the formula already in
- But I'm also calculating a kind of 'summary ratio' of all the existing ratios.
- Therefore I need a bunch of (future) ratios that are currently 0 to 0, or my summary ratio will be messed up
- But this is returning an ugly #DIV/0! error for most of my future entries
- I have tried to use the IFERROR function to make these entries blank or zero
- But I'm getting a #NAME error
- Here is my basic formula (which correctly returns a ratio such as "5:1":

> **=A1/G1&":"&A2/G1**

Where:

**A1 is the first number

A2 is the second number

G1 is the already-calculated GCD**

- Here is my attempted formula to attempt to return a blank cell if a DIV error is returned (i.e when both numbers are zero, in all my future, yet-to-be filled in entries)

> **=IFERROR(A1/G1&":"&A2/G1,"")**

What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: I am still using Excel 2002 but have the Analysis ToolPack installed (which BTW fixed an earlier problem where my ratio formula itself returned a NAME error)

Thanks in advance for any wise words!

Comment: Maybe IFERROR was introduced after Excel 2002? Try `=IF(G1=0,"",A1/G1&":"&A2/G1)`?

Comment: IFERROR is available [from Excel 2007](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611).

Comment: Thanks champs - it worked! So grateful to have such a brains trust!

Answer (score 0):

If `IFERROR` isn't available in your Excel version, then check for zero directly:

```
=IF(G1=0,"",A1/G1&":"&A2/G1)
```